# 32bit to 64bit Declaring Functions in 64 bit office

Tags: vba, function, 64-bit

So I had to go in and add in `PtrSafe` before function calls since I am now using 64bit Excel.  So far doing the `PtrSafe` changes has worked fine except for my `mod_Ping`.  I had to do a `#If Win64 Then` … `#else` … `#end if` statements to make this code work in my macros because it would not work in this part if I had just added in the `PtrSafe` before each function call.

```
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetHostByName Lib "wsock32.dll" Alias "gethostbyname" (ByVal HostName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSAStartup Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal wVersionRequired&, lpWSAdata As WSAdata) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSACleanup Lib "wsock32.dll" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IcmpCreateFile Lib "icmp.dll" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IcmpCloseHandle Lib "icmp.dll" (ByVal HANDLE As LongPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IcmpSendEcho Lib "ICMP" (ByVal IcmpHandle As LongPtr, ByVal DestAddress As LongPtr, ByVal RequestData As String, ByVal RequestSize As Integer, RequestOptns As IP_OPTION_INFORMATION, ReplyBuffer As IP_ECHO_REPLY, ByVal ReplySize As LongPtr, ByVal Timeout As LongPtr) As Boolean

Public Function Ping(sAddr As String, Optional Timeout As Integer = 2000) As Integer
  Dim hFile As LongPtr, lpWSAdata As WSAdata
  Dim hHostent As Hostent, AddrList As LongPtr
  Dim Address As LongPtr, rIP As String
  Dim OptInfo As IP_OPTION_INFORMATION
  Dim EchoReply As IP_ECHO_REPLY

  Call WSAStartup(&H101, lpWSAdata)

  If GetHostByName(sAddr + String(64 - Len(sAddr), 0)) <> SOCKET_ERROR Then
      CopyMemory hHostent.h_name, ByVal GetHostByName(sAddr + String(64 - Len(sAddr), 0)), Len(hHostent)
      CopyMemory AddrList, ByVal hHostent.h_addr_list, 4
      CopyMemory Address, ByVal AddrList, 4
  End If

  hFile = IcmpCreateFile()

  If hFile = 0 Then
      Ping = -2 ' MsgBox "Unable to Create File Handle"
      Exit Function
  End If

  OptInfo.TTL = 255

  If IcmpSendEcho(hFile, Address, String(32, "A"), 32, OptInfo, EchoReply, Len(EchoReply) + 8, Timeout) Then
      rIP = CStr(EchoReply.Address(0)) + "." + CStr(EchoReply.Address(1)) + "." + CStr(EchoReply.Address(2)) + "." + CStr(EchoReply.Address(3))
  Else
      Ping = -1 ' MsgBox "Timeout"
  End If

  If EchoReply.Status = 0 Then
      Ping = EchoReply.RoundTripTime
  Else
      Ping = -3
  End If

  IcmpCloseHandle hFile
  WSACleanup

End Function
#Else


Private Declare  Function GetHostByName Lib "wsock32.dll" Alias "gethostbyname" (ByVal HostName As String) As Long
Private Declare  Function WSAStartup Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal wVersionRequired&, lpWSAdata As WSAdata) As Long
Private Declare  Function WSACleanup Lib "wsock32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
Private Declare Function IcmpCreateFile Lib "icmp.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function IcmpCloseHandle Lib "icmp.dll" (ByVal HANDLE As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare Function IcmpSendEcho Lib "ICMP" (ByVal IcmpHandle As Long, ByVal DestAddress As Long, ByVal RequestData As String, ByVal RequestSize As Integer, RequestOptns As IP_OPTION_INFORMATION, ReplyBuffer As IP_ECHO_REPLY, ByVal ReplySize As Long, ByVal Timeout As Long) As Boolean

Public Function Ping(sAddr As String, Optional Timeout As Integer = 2000) As Integer
  Dim hFile As Long, lpWSAdata As WSAdata
  Dim hHostent As Hostent, AddrList As Long
  Dim Address As Long, rIP As String
  Dim OptInfo As IP_OPTION_INFORMATION
  Dim EchoReply As IP_ECHO_REPLY

  Call WSAStartup(&H101, lpWSAdata)

  If GetHostByName(sAddr + String(64 - Len(sAddr), 0)) <> SOCKET_ERROR Then
      CopyMemory hHostent.h_name, ByVal GetHostByName(sAddr + String(64 - Len(sAddr), 0)), Len(hHostent)
      CopyMemory AddrList, ByVal hHostent.h_addr_list, 4
      CopyMemory Address, ByVal AddrList, 4
  End If

  hFile = IcmpCreateFile()

  If hFile = 0 Then
      Ping = -2 ' MsgBox "Unable to Create File Handle"
      Exit Function
  End If

  OptInfo.TTL = 255

  If IcmpSendEcho(hFile, Address, String(32, "A"), 32, OptInfo, EchoReply, Len(EchoReply) + 8, Timeout) Then
      rIP = CStr(EchoReply.Address(0)) + "." + CStr(EchoReply.Address(1)) + "." + CStr(EchoReply.Address(2)) + "." + CStr(EchoReply.Address(3))
  Else
      Ping = -1 ' MsgBox "Timeout"
  End If

  If EchoReply.Status = 0 Then
      Ping = EchoReply.RoundTripTime
  Else
      Ping = -3
  End If

  IcmpCloseHandle hFile
  WSACleanup
#End If
End Function
```

As you can see I had to also change the longs to `LongPtr` as well.

When I open up this work book it gives me  error only comments may appear after end sub end function or end property.  The strange thing is, if i just ignore this and close out the debugger the workbook works fine.

I mean the `#End if` should be there to end the initial `#If` calling so I don't know why I would get a compile error for it.  Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: The declaration is just wrong.  DWORD in the MSDN documentation is Long in VBA, not LongPtr.  The ip-address is Long as well.

Comment: @HansPassant i went and changed that, it still doesn't resolve the issue of why i am getting a compile error

Comment: Do focus on the line number that produces the compile error.  Notable is that the #End If is placed incorrectly, if Win64 is defined then the compiler will see two End Function statements.  It needs to go after it.

Comment: @HansPassant Hey hans thanks for the reply, i actually tried that before, but what happens is that if i close the work book and re-open the entire thing crashes and i have to re-open the workbook by disabling macros...

By defining Win64, do you mean declaring it before i use the way i would dim an object?

Comment: I think **all** `Declare` statements have to come before any user defined `Sub/Function`. Try one `#If Win64 Then … Else …` for the declares first and another afterwards for the user defined `Ping` function

Answer (score 2):

I think our problem here is that **32bit** Excel changes data type Integer to Long data type.
Try replacing `Integer` with `LongPtr`.

- `Long` only works for **32bit** Excel
- `LongLong` only works for **64bit** Excel
- `LongPtr` works for both **32bit** and **64bit** as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview

Answer (score 1):

The End Function is outside of the #End If, but the Function is INSIDE of the #If.  So basically you need to swap the last 2 lines around.